# How can I emulate a form submission with a javascript File object?

Tags: javascript, django, html

So I have a file object created from a drag and drop into an area from desktop. Now things all dandy, until I have to upload it via Ajax to a Django backend. I would like to utilize the nice Django utils such as request.FILES, etc.

Right now, I'm messing with some existing code here:

```
xhr.open("post", s.post, true);

            // Set appropriate headers
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-file-name", file.fileName);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-file-size", file.fileSize);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("x-file-type", file.
            xhr.send(file);
```

Try as I might, it doesn't seem to be emulate a form with a file input submission. Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Could've sworn file uploads aren't permitted over AJAX? Yep, just confirmed. You can sort of get around the limitation with an iframe containing a file upload field and some javascript (there's some drop-in functionality out there), but over XHR is pure no-no.

Comment: @chrisdpratt - welcome to HTML5 :-)

Comment: I totally missed that tag, and I'm still in assume greatest browser support mode. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a "FormData" object and then append the file to that as a parameter.

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("theFile", yourFileObject);
    //
    // ... set up the xhr ...
    //
    xhr.send(fd);
```

Obviously this only works in HTML5 environments, but if you're messing with the File stuff that's probably something you're dealing with.

Comment: what are some sane defaults for xhr?

Comment: Well, you need to give it a URL etc.  There's not much else to it. [Here](http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/) is a random blog post with some example code (that does other stuff as well). You don't have to set the header stuff up; the new HTML5 xhr object just knows how to do that.

Comment: are you sure that is all i need? i've experiemented with the formdata, it seems to be sending well. but still django is still not seeing it as a file.

Comment: Hmm well I *think* that's what you're supposed to do ... You might try using a tool like the "Network" tab in Chrome developer tools, or the "TamperData" or "Firebug" plugins for Firefox, to see what the HTTP request actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot upload a file using the XmlHttpRequest object because it is not supported.

There have been hacky workarounds (like using an iFrame) and recently there is a new File api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications) for HTML 5 for browsers that support it.

If you search a little more on stackoverflow, you can find examples on how to do the workarounds.

Comment: It is supported in HTML5, and the HTML5 world is where one would find such things as the "File" object under discussion.  You're right, however, that it's a new thing.